# Gaussian Surface for insulated plates have charge Separation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I was wondering the most suitable Gaussian Surface to choose that would allow me solve the electric field easily.

Given 2 insulating infinitely long plates that have charge separation.
We need to find the Electric Field Intensity at points 1,2 and 3 respectively.

[image: Diagram]

What would be the most suitable Gaussian Surface to choose for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charge separation is of no use, think of it as four big plates and use the formula of infinite plate $\frac{Q}{2a}\epsilon_0$ and keep in mind the direction of the field exerted by the plates at the given point . If you want it to solve it by taking a Gaussian surface then take it as a cuboid passing through the plates.